# Disabling pagination with paginate tag pair failing?

Tags: channel-entries, pagination

I just disabled pagination on a channel "main index" page while my paginate codes were still in my template and result was that all pagination tags and html content was coming out as-is breaking the page totally. Should those be ignored totally when disabling them?

I mean, now I have to delete pagination codes or at least comment them out to "save" the template settings if I ever need pagination again.

EE2.9.2

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. If you want to report a bug, please report it to EllisLab directry, as this is community-powered site.

Comment: Before I report a bug there, I wanted to ask, if someone else have had similar situation like I have. I know this is community-powered site. Nice welcome there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All tags that the system does not know (e.g. references to variables or fields that don't exist, or just any text wrapped between {}) is returned to the template unparsed. If you disable pagination, the system stops knowing anything about paginate tags, so they stay unparsed.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt know that, thought it just ignores tags if disabled.